# Getting first video frame to display by default in Safari web browser on Mac

Tags: video, safari

I have a couple of videos to display on my WordPress site. These videos are hosted locally on the site. In all major browsers except for Safari I can see the first frame of the video displaying by default. But in Safari there is just a black screen with a play button showing. How can I display the first frame in Safari? Is this doable? Is this something users can change in their Safari settings?

```
<div style="width: 50%; float: left; padding-right: 4px">
  [video mp4="https://somesite.com/beta/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/vid1.mp4"][/video]
</div>
```